# Invalid structure size when marshalling c structure to .NET

Tags: vb.net, marshalling, wrapper, sizeof, structure

I'm experiencing a problem with the following c-structure:

```
typedef struct tagTEXTUREPROP
{
   DWORD  dwSize;
   DOUBLE eGloss;
   DOUBLE eContrast;
   BOOL   bRepeat;
   DOUBLE eDropX;
   DOUBLE eDropY;
   DOUBLE ePlacingPointX;
   DOUBLE ePlacingPointY;
   DOUBLE eWidth;
   DOUBLE eHeight;
   LONG   nTransformation;
} 
TEXTUREPROP;
```

Where

```
TYPE     C/C++            Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------
DWORD    unsigned long    Unsigned 32-bit integer.
DOUBLE   double           Double precision floating point (64-bit).
BOOL     int              Signed 32-bit integer.
LONG     long             Signed 32-bit integer.
```

What I understand from the code above and the definition is that the size of the structure must be 76 bytes. This is what the original DLL function I am currently using expects as the value for the structure member dwSize. Any other value generates an invalid structure size error message.

I'm generating an .NET wrapper and so I have to do some marshalling. Here is my translation of the structure:

```
  <StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit)> 
  Friend Structure TEXTUREPROP
    <FieldOffset(0)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public dwSize As UInteger
    <FieldOffset(4)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public eGloss As Double
    <FieldOffset(12)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public eContrast As Double
    <FieldOffset(20)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I4)> Public bRepeat As Integer
    <FieldOffset(24)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public eDropX As Double
    <FieldOffset(32)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public eDropY As Double
    <FieldOffset(40)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public ePlacingPointX As Double
    <FieldOffset(48)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public ePlacingPointY As Double
    <FieldOffset(56)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public eWidth As Double
    <FieldOffset(64)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.R8)> Public eHeight As Double
    <FieldOffset(72)> <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.I4)> Public nTransformation As Integer
  End Structure
```

To calculate the size of the structure, I use the following code:

```
Dim pFTP As New TEXTUREPROP With {.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(TEXTUREPROP))}
```

But the resulting value for dwSize is now 80 and not 76, which leads to the invalid structure size error mentioned above.

```
When I change the structure to:

<StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size:=76, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
  Friend Structure FACE_TEXTUREPROP
    [...]
  End Structure
```

The Marshal.SizeOf obviously calculates a size of 76 and it works with the DLL function, but it leaves me with some bad feelings. Is there any wrong? Are there any errors which I don't think of right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explicit layout you specified is incompatible with the default Pack value for [StructLayout].  The default is 8 which requires an extra 4 bytes of padding to be inserted before the Double to keep it aligned.  The pinvoke marshaller flubs this a bit by still calculating the structure size based on the packing.

Fix this by specifying the packing explicitly:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack:=4)> _
Friend Structure TEXTUREPROP
    '' etc
End Structure
```

Setting the Size property explicitly will fix it too:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size:=76)> _
'' etc
```

The bigger advantage of specifying the packing correctly is that you now no longer need to explicitly specify the offsets anymore.  Just the plain LayoutKind.Sequential will work correctly.

Comment: Your are right. The only thing I have to mention is that when I use drop the offsets I have to make the LayoutKind.Sequential again.